# Installing Google Cloud SDK on CENTOS: Not finding correct Python version

Tags: python, linux, server, google-cloud-platform, centos

When I type:

`yum install google-cloud-sdk`

I get an error saying that it requires a version of python greater than or equal to 2.7.

I do have 2.7 installed, but when I type `python -V` it says 2.6.6.

I am using CENTOS 6.10

How can I fix this error, and install the Google Cloud SDK?

Comment: I would uninstall both versions first and reboot. Then install the correct version of Python and Pip. Your problem is a PATH problem and having two incorrect installations will give you grief in the future.

Comment: First, you should avoid Red Hat products if you want modern components. Avoid Red Hat and CentOS like the plague. Second, if you want Red Hat with modern components, then use Fedora. Fedora usually provides the latest release for all components it supplies. Third, if you must use CentOS, then enable [Software Collections (SCL)](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) to get newer components. The SCL still provides older components, but they are not ancient like Red Hat supplies.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of Red Hat products? I am just setting this up on a new server, so it isn't too much hassle for me to switch.

Comment: Red Hat and CentOS are fine to use. For CentOS, I would use a current version instead of an old version. I prefer Debian, followed by Ubuntu. However, this is a personal preference and not a product recommendation. Select the OS that you know the best or prefer to invest time to learn. Note: some studies report that Ubuntu is the most popular Linux OS in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to not rely on an OS-specific pre-packaged SDK which comes with dependencies that *might* hurt your ability to install/upgrade the SDK itself or its components at will (if using packages not built by Google, since you'd need to wait for those packages to become available).

For that you can just download the latest generic linux SDK (the `google-cloud-sdk-<version>-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` file) from [Installing from versioned archives](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives#archive) (or an older version from [the archive GCS bucket](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/cloud-sdk-release?authuser=0) if you want) - which you can unpack in a convenient location (personally I picked `/usr/local`). It is pretty self-contained, which allows to even have multiple SDK versions side by side - I did that and I can switch between versions at will using symlinks. This is how it looks like:

```
my_laptop:/usr/local> ls -la | grep google-cloud-sdk
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root        20 Feb 26 22:30 google-cloud-sdk -> google-cloud-sdk-236
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root       342 Jun 14  2018 google-cloud-sdk-204
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root       342 Dec 17  2018 google-cloud-sdk-228
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root       342 Feb 26 22:33 google-cloud-sdk-236
```

And to not have to mess with the path I just symlinked the desired SDK executables from the `current` version into `/usr/local/bin` (which I already have in my path):

```
my_laptop:/usr/local/bin> ls -la | grep google-cloud-sdk
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 Aug  9  2016 gcloud -> /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 Aug  9  2016 gsutil -> /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil
```

In general this should work on a wide variety of Linux variants (the versions I have installed worked just fine with my pretty archaic OpenSuSE 13.3 and survived a complete OS re-install to OpenSuSE Leap 15.0).

This approach should be completely opaque to your package manager (so don't try to upgrade using that) and can even be done as a regular user, not necessarily as root (if needed).

You probably still need to figure out your python version issue in order to use the SDK. If `python -V` it says 2.6.6 then you also have that version installed and it is the preferred one over 2.7. Your options:

- uninstall python 2.6
- invoke python using `python2.7` instead of just `python`:

  ```
  my_laptop:/usr/bin> python2.7  -V
  Python 2.7.14
  ```
- update your `/usr/bin/python` symlink to point to the version you desire:

  ```
  my_laptop:/usr/bin> ls -la | grep python
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Feb  6 13:04 python -> python2.7
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Feb  6 13:04 python2 -> python2.7
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        6304 Feb  6 13:05 python2.7
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Jan 31 11:36 python3 -> python3.6
  -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root       10456 Jan 31 11:36 python3.6
  ```